# Can I get a unique TIMESTAMP for every record in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

Is there a possibility of getting a unique timestamp value for for each record in MySQL??..

I created a sample table

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id int primary key, name varchar(50), 
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP );
```

and ran some sample INSERTIONS and seems to be timestamp values are duplicated.

```
e.g  insert into t1(id,name) values(1,"test");
```

Comment: Unless you prevent records from being inserted at the same time, there can be duplicate timestamps.

Comment: @MichaelMior Can't I increase the "TIMESTAMP sensivity"??.. using milliseconds etc? Marcus Just Using a Select query. through naked eye I can see it.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support microseconds (yet, 5.6.4 will) so i'd suggest going with an integer field.

Comment: @Kostis You mean just using an Integer field and keep incrementing?.. How can I cope with an update??.. Find the largest integer value and add one?

Comment: @Ashan What about your use case isn't solved by an auto-incrementing primary key?

Comment: @MichaelMior then there will be a problem for updates?? Am I correct??.. If a field is updated increment value won't change, I want to identify the order where records have changed.

Comment: @Ashan, a simpler solution would be to use PHP microtime() function http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Comment: @Kostis My Application is in java. sorry I forgot to mention that :(

Comment: @Ashan :-) I'm not familiar with Java but i pretty sure that it offers a similar method of getting the systems' micro/nano time

Comment: @Kostis You mean get the system time using java code and store it other than using TIMESTAMP in MySQL. That's a good idea and I will be able to get a unique value.Thanks for the great tip. Sorry I can't up vote you.. :(.. really appreciate your help.:)

Comment: @Ashan glad i could be of assistance :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some day soon (5.6.4), MySQL will provide [fractional seconds](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html) in `TIMESTAMP` columns, however, even fractional seconds aren't guaranteed to be unique. Though theoretically, they'd most often be unique, especially if you limited MySQL to a single thread.

You can use a [UUID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) if you need a unique number that is ordered temporally.

---

`SELECT UUID();` yields something like:

```
45f9b8d6-8f00-11e1-8920-842b2b55ce56
```

And some time later:

```
004b721a-8f01-11e1-8920-842b2b55ce56
```

The first three portions of a UUID consist of the time, however, they're in order from highest precision to least, so you'd need to reverse the first three portions using `SUBSTR()` and `CONCAT()` like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR(UUID(), 16, 3), '-', SUBSTR(UUID(), 10, 4),
  '-', SUBSTR(UUID(), 1, 8))
```

Yields:

```
1e1-8f00-45f9b8d6
```

You obviously couldn't use a function like this as a default value, so you'd have to set it in code, but it's a guaranteed unique temporally ordered value. `UUID()` works at a much lower level than seconds (*clock cycles*), so it's guaranteed unique with each call and has low overhead (no locking like `auto_increment`).

Using the `UUID()` on the database server may be preferred to using a similar function, such as PHP's `microtime()` function on the application server because your database server is more centralized. You may have more than one *application (web) server*, which may generate colliding values, and `microtime()` still doesn't guarantee unique values.

---

### Useful reading for understanding the components of UUID

- [Universally unique identifier (UUID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)
- [Extracting timestamp and MAC address from UUIDs](https://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2014/06/mysql-extracting-timstamp-and-mac.html)

Comment: +1 great info. Few questions however arised. How does the three first numbers guarantee temporal order? Manual says just vaguely: "The first three numbers are generated from a timestamp." Should the full `UUID` be always used (just the first three values reversed for ordering)? Where to find more info about this function. Manual didn't mention the "highest precision to least" order?

Comment: @ZZ-bb, The MySQL manual doesn't include the details because the UUID format that they use is a [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9629399/toc.pdf). The fourth part of the UUID will change whenever you set the clock back. This is to ensure that the value as a whole is unique. As long as you don't mess with your clock, the first three parts are fine.

Comment: CORRECTION: the **third portion** of the UUID contains also a 4-bit "version" in the most significant bits, followed by the high 12 bits of the time (see ["UUID record layout"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format)). So in your example you incorrectly selected the _highest bits_ of the timestamp: instead of 16 you need to select **12** bits (i.e. select not 4, but 3 HEX digits). The correct selection of the _highest_ timestamp portion (from the _third chunk_ of the UUID) is `SUBSTRING(UUID(), 16, 3)` and the result will then be `1e1-8f00-45f9b8d6`.

Comment: The **correct** example with **thorough explanations** about how to extract timestamp  from UUIDs can be found in the following article: [Extracting timestamp and MAC address from UUIDs](https://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2014/06/mysql-extracting-timstamp-and-mac.html).

Answer (score 2):

Yes if you don't do two or more inserts or edits during one second. Only problem is that a lot stuff can be done during a second, i.e. multiple inserts or automatic updates using a `where` clause. That rules out the simple solution to force unique timestamps: to add `unique` constraint into `timestamp` column.

Why should a `timestamp` be unique? Use `auto increment` or something else if you need unique index etc.

If you need more precise time values than `timestamp`, see:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fractional-seconds.html (Note: fractional part is discarded during insert. Not helping...)
- http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/66849/ (Apparently `double(13,3)` makes it possible to add microtime into DB.)
- [MySQL greater than problem with microtime timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663504/mysql-greater-than-problem-with-microtime-timestamp) (`int` multiplied with 100 or 1000 could also work. Here `decimal` is preferred over `double`.)
- [Why doesn't MySQL support millisecond / microsecond precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572209/why-doesnt-mysql-support-millisecond-microsecond-precision)

Comment: thanks for the descriptive answer. Auto increment won't work for my problem. Since an update query executed. Then I can't detect the order of the records have changed. That's why I tried to use a TIMESTAMP.

Comment: @Ashan When inserting records `AI` reweals the order. But editing is a different story. Why edit order matters? I believe the main function of `timestamp` is to mark the time when changes made into a row so you know that the row has or has not changed after insert. Not to reveal the order of changes. Storing `microtime` into some column could be an answer but I don't think there's any guarantee that even that value is always unique. You could insert `date` or `timestamp` + some sort of count value of current date's edits. But then again, how to keep track of the edits?